# Add -30 minutes to date

Tags: php

I have this function

```
$timetable->start_time = $row{'deadline_time'} ? date('H:i', strtotime($row{'deadline_time'})) : ''; // start_time : Must be 24 hour format. For example: 18:00
$timetable->end_time = $row{'deadline_time'} ? date('H:i', strtotime($row{'deadline_time'})) : ''; // end_time : Must be 24 hour format. For example: 20:30
```

And i need to add -30 minutes to that time. How can I add it?

@UPDATE
I just update the code..
So the code is the same for start and end I just need to add -30 mins to the start. :)

Comment: what about previous day time ? I mean if time is 00:20 then ?

Comment: It seems that you forget to add start time before, `big mistake` now its your double effort to get start time from deadline time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime("-30 minutes"));
```

Lookup [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can add / substract specific lengths of time as follows:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date . '-30 minutes'));
```